# How can we retrieve sitecore items of specific language using fast query

Tags: sitecore

We are using below code to get Sitecore items using fast query:

```cs
db.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/test//*[@@templatename='test template name']");
```

But the problem with this code is that it gets items from all language versions.

Is there a way we can pass language parameter for fast query or how can we get items of specified language version using fast query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from John West:

> Fast query does not account for the context language (results include items with versions that match the query in any language)

More can be found here: [Sitecore Query Cheat Sheet](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet).

So the answer is: No, you cannot pass language to fast query.

Consider switching to Sitecore Content Search. Fast query is executed against SQL Server database directly. It doesn't scale. It can even kill your website if it's overused.